# Usage Threats of using Developer or Partner SF Organisation into ( Production Site developed in java or php)

Tags: licenses

I have a client website, where i am thinking to integrate sf business functionality into my live production site using dev or partner portal license which is free to use :).

I would like to know if there are any Legal threats are there, 
I understand all the governor limits, user llcense limitation, which is good for my requirement, what i am unsure about is the usage policies.

Its a looong agreement document with somany clauses, which is out of my scope to understand as a developer.

Can anybody throw some insight to threats involved in doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Development and Production. Doesn't that pretty much say it all? SF provides Development Orgs so people can learn the platform, experiment with new features and design/develop applications for the benefit of the community, NOT for production purposes.

If they gave them away for production purposes, they wouldn't make any money would they?